# External library (AJV) is not recognized when using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'm trying to use another json schema validator ([AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)) and the sample code provided works fine in JSFiddle when I use just plain java script like this

[AJV test - JSFiddle with no library (pure javascript)](https://jsfiddle.net/501874ea/4/)

```
var ajv = Ajv({allErrors: true});

var schema = {
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string" },
    "bar": { "type": "number", "maximum": 3 }
  }
};

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

test({"foo": "abc", "bar": 2});
test({"foo": 2, "bar": 4});

function test(data) {
  var valid = validate(data);
  if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
  else console.log('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
}
```

But when I try to use the same exact code as above in conjunction with Dojo

[AJV test - JSFiddle using Dojo 1.10.4](https://jsfiddle.net/pbq2yjxy/20/)

I get this error

> fiddle.jshell.net/pbq2yjxy/18/show/:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajv is not defined

How can I use AJV library with Dojo?

Comment: Both fiddle has the same code

Comment: Looks like the AJV has its own version of RequireJS. which might be conflicting with dojo's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global require is supplied by browserify, it conflicts with Dojo.
The solution is to load Ajv before Dojo.
It's resolved here: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/234